# Unsure about parameters when calling base constructor from derived class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, constructor, xna

I am having some troubles implementing inheritence into my game. I thought that it would be best to introduce inheritence, as it would make my code neater and organised in a logical way.

The problem i am facing atm is with the parameters when calling the constructor from the base class in the derived class.

I am using the Paddle class as the base class and the Player class as the class inheriting Paddle.

The code is shown below:

***In the Paddle class....***

```
//properties

  protected Texture2D pTexture;
  protected Vector2 pPosition;
  protected Vector2 pVelocity;


//constructor for Paddle class (only first line here, as the rest is irrelevant)

public Paddle(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour)
```

***In the Player class....***

```
//properties
PlayerIndex pID;


//constructor for Player class (only first line here, as the rest is irrelevant)
public Player(PlayerIndex newID) : base()
```

Before you mention the reason why its not working is because the base constructor im calling in the Player class doesn't have any parameters, whereas the constructor in the base class/Paddle class does, i understand that. The problem i am facing is setting the texture, position, etc of the player but the texture, position, etc are in the base class, as they are common properties for the Player and Enemy class (another class that inherits from Paddle but it's similar to Player, hence only mentioning it now). I also don't know what to put as the parameters when calling the base constructor in the Player class.

Thanks for reading and for the help in advance :-)

ADDED CODE I'VE CHANGED BELOW:

```
public Player(PlayerIndex newID, Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour)
        : base(newTexture, newPosition, theViewport, newColour)
```

Comment: If you are unsure about it then I believe you got your inheritance structure wrong. Your current code is saying that a player class will have all the properties from Paddle class, but it doesn't seem like that.

Comment: What's the question? You know why it doesn't work. so why don't you just pass the required parameters to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the constructor in this way, you have to give the derived constructor ALL of the information needed for the base constructor, so that it can call it like so:

```
public Player(PlayerIndex newID, Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour)
```

You then pass to the base:

```
public Player(PlayerIndex newID, Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour) : base(newTexture, newPosition, theViewport, newColour);
```

Obviously this makes the Player constructor quite a bit larger. To avoid this problem, you could declare an `Init()` function on the base class (non-overridable) that takes all the parameters the constructor does, and have the owning class call it after instantiation. Either way, you have to give the class all the information eventually.

Let me know if I can clarify anything or help further!.

**Update**

1. Yes, the `:base(...)` syntax is effectively the same thing as writing (if it were valid C#) `myBaseClassPointer = new base(...);` (where base is Paddle in this case). Again, this is not valid C#. You actually have to use :base to instantiate the base class when using a non-default constructor. It sets properties the same way as if you had instantiated it directly, and as long as they are not marked private, they will be available from the derived class (child is a bit of misnomer, since that term generally refers to composition).
2. I'm not recommending the use of an `Init()` function, as the using class isn't guaranteed to call it. That being said, it could work pretty well like so:

   ```
   class Player
   {
      private bool initialized = false;
      public Player()
      {}

      public void Init(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour)
      {
         //All the stuff your constructor used to do
         initialized = true;
      }

      public void SomeFunctionUsingVariables()
      {
      if (initialized)
      { //Do whatever }
      }
   }
   ```

The only advantage is you don't have to pass all the data that Init() needs to the Player constructor, so knowledge of these fields doesn't need to exist in the Player class itself. It works, as long as the extra if checks are ok and you remember to call `Init` in the instantiating class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added some code (to the end of the question part of this thread above) which is what you have said here, although it's slightly different. 

Something i dont understand is if i pass newTexture, etc as a parameter when calling the base class from Player class, what does the parameter refer to? Does it mean that the parameter will be used in the Paddle/base class and modify the properties in the base class, which then i can call from the child class? Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean about making a Init() Function... I mean if you could explain in a bit more detail, i may hopefully understand it quite quickly, as i am fairly familiar with using something like this.... thanks v much

Comment: The update has helped, as i understand that the parameters in the derived class' constructor used when calling the base constructor from there is just the same as manipulating the properties directly from the base class.... thanks v much for the help! I will make some changes and let you know if i run into any other problems, or related problems, so i will keep this thread/question open for a while and if there's no problems, ill upvote, etc... thanks again! :D

Comment: Ok, so i have moved methods, etc into the Player class from the Paddle class... that are only relevent to the Player. the Only problem atm is that the player isnt drawn straight away... thanks

Comment: Great! Just making sure, you aren't asking an additional question, correct? I wouldn't want to accidentally ignore it!

Comment: Sorry, i should have made it clearer... basically the problem im having atm is that i have a draw method in the base and derived class. The draw method in the base class is virtual and is overriden in the derived class (player). In my game, i have a countdown screen, so i am implementing this via game states. I want to draw the playing game screen whilst this is counting down, so i call drawPlayingGamescreen... which worked before, however now it doesnt work, as everything is drawn normally apart from the player, but after the countdown reaches 0, the player is drawn...

Comment: I would definitely need to see the code before I could diagnose anything. You may want to consider asking this as a separate question, or you could edit the existing one.

Comment: ok, i will ask this as a different question... i will send u the link to it also.... thanks

Comment: ok... i have created another question for this... the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121689/player-not-drawn-during-countdown-before-game-screen-xna

Answer (score 0):

Since the paddle object has properties that are shared by both `Player` and `Enemy`, composition is a better choice than inheritance. (Via inheritance you cannot shre a base object since that object gets independly constructed for each object) Implementation involves constructing a (shared) `Paddle` that is then passed to the c-tor for `Player` and `Enemy`.

I am not sure why `Paddle` properties such as position and velocity are shared. `ViewPort` seems to be the only property that should be shared. If this a game like Pong or the like, each player has its own location and velocity but both are drawn on the same GUI component. If that is the case, both Player and Enemy are paddles and inheritnace is fine, but the ViewPort then is shared. Implementation involves consructing a `ViewPort` and passing it, along with the `Player`'s (or `Enemy`'s) location, velocity, etc to the `Player` (or `Enemy`) c-tor which will then pass them onto the base `Paddle` c-tor

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, he is not trying to share a paddle (he would obviously need different positions, potentially different textures, etc). Is a Player a "type of" Paddle? Maybe, maybe not. An argument could be made either direction depending on the polymorphic behavior for each class. I would actually lean towards inheritance here (not seeing any of the rest of the code of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Basically im treating a Player and Enemy as a type of Paddle, as i had only a Paddle class before but was used just for the player... but the name could be improved, hence creation of the player class. I will have a player with it's own postion, texture, etc and an enemy with its own position, etc... but what they have in common, i.e. they both have a position, texture, etc i have kept in the paddle class.