# Player not drawn during countdown before game screen XNA

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, xna

Basically before i implemented inheritence into my game, introducing 2 new classes, player and enemy, (not using enemy atm), the level was loaded and drawn (including the player paddle) during the countdown screen (the countdown before the level starts).

Now all of the level is drawn apart from the player paddle when i have implemented inheritence into my game, inheriting from a class called Paddle, where the Player and Enemy classes are derived classes. I have experimented between overriding the draw method in the player class from the base/paddle class and then using the draw method in the base class.

Maybe it's nothing to do with the draw method necessarily but all i know is that the player isnt being drawn during the countdown screen but when the countdown screen finishes, the player is drawn. This may seem like a small problem or change but it's really frustrating, as i cant work out what's causing this.

The relevent code is provided below:

***code from the player class***

```
//constructor
public Player(PlayerIndex newID, Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour)
        : base(newTexture, newPosition, theViewport, newColour)


public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(pTexture, pPosition, pRectangle, pColour);
        //base.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
    }
```

***code from the paddle class***

```
//constructor
public Paddle(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Viewport theViewport, Color newColour)
    {
        pTexture = newTexture;
        pPosition = newPosition;

        //theres more code here but it's assigning parameter values to properties in this class
    }

public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {                        
        pRectangle = new Rectangle((int)pPosition.X, (int)pPosition.Y, pWidth, pHeight);            

    }

    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(pTexture, pPosition, pRectangle, pColour);
    }
```

***code from game1 class***

```
public void DrawPreGameCountdownScreen(GameTime gameTime)
    {         
        DrawPlayingGameScreen(gameTime);

        //more code here but it's irrelevent....
    }


public void DrawPlayingGameScreen(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        DrawBlocks(gameTime);
        player1.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);

        //more code here... but irrelevent to this...

    }
```

The player1 is obviously the player and it's of type Player and not Paddle (as i have made the Paddle class abstract... as i don't want to allow for creating a Paddle object directly).

I have put all of the properties in the Paddle class as protected also.

I am also using game states to differentiate between different points in the game, so in the update method for the countdown screen it basically decreases the value of the timer and before that checks that the timer isnt at 0 before doing so, otherwise the state changes.

As i say, this worked perfectly before, so i assume that its something to do with the player class or something ive done wrong.

If you need any more info, please feel free to ask and any ideas/solutions, etc please let me know :).

Thank you v much for the help in advanced.

Comment: Your code looks pretty good, are you sure DrawPlayingGameScreen is getting called during the countdown?

Comment: In addition to that, have you verified it is being drawn at the correct position? Try using a break point to see if your code is being hit

Comment: LordTakkera: Thanks :)... i have been unsure about how good my code is, as this is my first game. I am sure that DrawPlayingGameScreen is being called during the countdown, as the code above shows it being called in the DrawPregameCountDown method but i haven't called it in the updatePreGameCountDown method, as then the player would be able to move, etc ... although i could do this or i could just make a boolean to stop the player moving whilst the countdown is executing.

Comment: Cyral: I have some code that i haven't included that positions the paddle in the correct position. I am sure this works, as after the countdown screen it appears in the correct and intended position, although i did check this before via placing a breakpoint at the necessary line of code, however as i say its positioned correctly after the countdown method, it's position is set initially at the beginning of each level and isnt altered until the countdown finishes and also it was working before i introduced the player class, so i was only using the paddle class.

Comment: Update being called would only matter if it set some variable used by the draw function that isn't initialized properly. FYI, when a programmer asks "are you sure X is getting called" he means "If you set a breakpoint in that function, does it get hit **when you expect**" Many, many times the code will say that it is called (as yours clearly does) but for some reason the call never actually happens. Tracing the problem up the call stack generally results in finding the root problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies btw. Apologies LordTakkera, I wasn't sure what you meant before when you asked if the method was getting called but thanks for letting me know :). The player1.draw DOES get hit when i expect it to and it goes to the draw function in the paddle class, as im not using the overriden draw method in the player class, as it doesnt differ at all from the one in the base class.

Comment: No problem, just a good thing to know (especially when working with live programmers). So now the next question is, is there anything different about the values being passed to the function in countdown, as opposed to in-game. (Again, this is a set-a-breakpoint-and-check kind of thing) For example, in Update you set the pRectangle property. If this isn't set before Update is called, it could be getting drawn off-screen (or at 0 size)

Comment: I think you have solved it!... I mean i have just checked as u said the values when the player1.draw is called from the countdown method... well when that calls the playingamescreen method which calls the player1.draw method... and the values for rectangle seem to all be 0... included the X and Y values... so im assuming this is the problem or a big part of it... i will try and alter it and get back to you. Thanks... :D!

Comment: Posted as an answer, let me know if it fixes it!

Comment: Ok, so i have just copied and pasted that line in the draw method in the player class just to check it was that (as if there was any doubt :D) and it works. I don't quite understand at this point how it was working before, i mean because the update method from the paddle class wasn't called when i only had the paddle class. Thanks v much... this has caused me alot of hassle and frustration up till now! :D...

Comment: Perhaps you had initialized it correctly before and it worked? Anyways, I'm glad you figured it out. I added the debugging practices I mentioned earlier to my answer, hopefully you find them useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paddle's `Update` function you initialize the pRectangle member (used in drawing). If this member isn't initialized in another place (to the starting location), you are likely drawing a zero-size rectangle during the countdown, thus it doesn't appear.

The reason you don't just get an exception is that `Rectangle` is a struct and so cannot not be null unless you declare it as a `Rectangle?`. Instead its members get initialized to default values (0 for numeric types).

A general piece of advice when debugging:

1. Check to make sure the code in question is **actually being called**. Set a breakpoint and make sure it gets hit.
2. If it is, **check that the data at the breakpoint is correct**. Uninitialized value types can really bite you, so check for those if it looks like you are getting a bunch of default values.

Comment: Thanks LordTakkera. I stupidly was only checking the values of postition before when debugging and not the value of pRectangle... just a quick question, would you advise me to declare the pRectangle as Rectangle? so that i would recieve some error if i happen to experience this type of problem again, or does that incur different problems, etc? Thanks

Comment: Rectangle is very important when drawing with SpriteBatch. Glad you figured it out!